# Solve $y = \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{1}{16x^4}$ by completing a perfect square, with a given domain.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, completing-the-square

Problem:

> $$y = \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{1}{16x^4} \text{ for } 4 \le x \le 25$$
>
> *Solve by completing the square and use regular anti-derivatives.*

Not even sure where to begin. I'm taking online classes and the professor is useless. The only completing the square I know of is when given a trinomial, which I do not have. I'm not looking for someone to do the work or give me the answer, but to just help me out with the steps so I can do it on my own.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a quite important part of the question...

Comment: Do you have to set $y$ equal to some value and then solve for x?

Comment: I have not forgotten anything. This is all we were given with those instructions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is unclear. What does it mean to "solve" this?

Comment: It's under the section of line length if that gives an help..."using direct integration, do NOT use a calculator. Solve by completing the square and use regular antiderivatives."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise is about the arc length of that curve.

By definition, you have that the arc length is given by

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2 + 1}\ \text{d}x$$

In your case, the extrema $a$ and $b$ regimen:

$$a = 4 ~~~~~~~ b = 25$$

Your $y$ is given too, so you have to take its derivative:

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = x^5 - \frac{1}{4x^5}$$

Hence

$$\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2 = x^{10} + \frac{1}{16x^{10}} - \frac{1}{2}$$

So you have to evaluate this:

$$\int_4^25 \sqrt{x^{10} + \frac{1}{16x^{10}} - \frac{1}{2} + 1}\ \text{d}x = \int_4^25 \sqrt{x^{10} + \frac{1}{16x^{10}} + \frac{1}{2}}\ \text{d}x$$

**Evaluation**

This is actually easy, because what you have under the square root is nothing but a perfect square like the previous one, but with a + sign instead of a minus sign:

$$x^{10} + \frac{1}{16x^{10}} + \frac{1}{2} \equiv \left(x^5 + \frac{1}{4x^5}\right)^2$$

Hence the square and the square root are simplified, obtaining:

$$\int_4^{25} \left(x^5 + \frac{1}{4x^5}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

Which is trivial and you shall do it by yourself.

**Complete Solution**

In case you are completely lost, here it is.

You can split the integral in two parts, and the first integral is

$$\int_4^{25} x^5\ \text{d}x = \frac{x^6}{6}\bigg|_4^{25} = \frac{25^6}{6} - \frac{4^6}{6} = \frac{81378843}{2}$$

The second one:

$$\int_4^{25} \frac{1}{4x^5}\ \text{d}x = \frac{1}{4}\int_4^{25} \frac{1}{x^5}\ \text{d}x = -\frac{1}{16x^4}\bigg|_4^{25} = \frac{390369}{400000000}$$

So finally:

$$\frac{81378843}{2} + \frac{390369}{400000000} = \frac{16275768600390369}{400000000} \approx 4.06\cdot 10^7$$

Comment: Feel like someone hit a light switch in my head. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm real confused as to why my professor said to not use a calculator. Is there some way to avoid using a calculator in this situation?

Comment: @Kalookakoo Probably your professor didn't want you to go through the real end of the problem. I mean, maybe he just wanted you to solve the integral, leaving the numerical part out!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: From the comments, it sounds as though you're being asked to find the arc length of this curve between the given values. This is
$$\int_4^{25}\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+1}\,dx
    = \int_4^{25}\sqrt{\left(-\frac{1}{4x^5} + x^5\right)^2+1}\,dx.$$
Now expand, and complete the square as the hint says.

Comment: Alright. So I'm trying to expand, complete the square to make it easy to get the sqrt, then solve, right? I seem to be stuck at x^10+1/(16x^2)+1/2, not sure what that turns into...